# React Native + Redux Form : Wizard Form handleSubmit

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I am trying to create wizard form in react native with the help of this [example](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/wizard/). but handleSubmit is not working.

**Signup.js**

```
submitForm(values){
 console.log("formValues",values);
}

nextPage(){
 this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 });
}

render(){
 const { page } = this.state;
 {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage nextPage={this.nextPage} />}
 {page === 2 && <WizardFormSecondPage nextPage={this.nextPage} />}
 {page === 3 && <WizardFormThirdPage onSubmit={this.submitForm}  />}
}
```

WizardFormFirstPage and WizardFormSecondPage works fine. but when it comes on WizardFormThirdPage it doesn't do anything (I can't see any console log in my terminal for validations and submitForm function). here is the code written.

**WizardFormThirdPage.js**

```
const WizardFormThirdPage = props => {
const { handleSubmit, onSubmit } = props;
return (
 <View>
  <Field name="street" component={InputField} label="Street" />
  <Button style= {{ margin: 10 }} block primary onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <Text>Continue</Text>
  </Button>
 </View>
 );
};
export default reduxForm({
 form: 'signup', //                 <------ same form name
 destroyOnUnmount: false, //        <------ preserve form data
 forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
 validate,
})(WizardFormThirdPage);
```

Comment: Maybe dumb question, but what library is the `Button` from?  Don't now what the `block` prop does. Have you tried to run other functions in you `onPress`?

Comment: i am using native base library. onPress is working fine . block and primary are variables from native base library.

Comment: Getting the issue. Has anyone found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late but I figured out what I was doing wrong.

While wrapping the react native InputText component with the redux form Field component. We have to pass props to the InputText component. I was passing props like this ...

```
<InputText {...props} />
```

The {...props} attaches all the event handlers like onChange, onSubmit, etc to the component so we don't have to do it manually. The issue lies here, that the InputText component has a **onChangeText** property rather than **onChange** which redux form injects into the props.

The correct way to do this is ..

```
const renderInput = ({ input: { onChange, ...restInput }}) => {
  return <TextInput style={styles.input} onChangeText={onChange} {...restInput} />
}

const Form = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Email:</Text>
      <Field name="email" component={renderInput} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This answer came from the article [Simple React Native forms with redux-form](http://esbenp.github.io/2017/01/06/react-native-redux-form-immutable-styled-components/).